# How to add the pattern regexp in HTML for the following condition?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm still actively trying to understand how regexp works but I need to work a regexp based on the following conditions:

1. Only allow the length of the input to be exactly 7
2. The first 4 can only be letter
3. The last 3 can only be numbers from 0 to 9
4. The 4th of the word can be a space if there are only 3 letters given and numbers were then followed.

Thanks.
P/S: I'm not a developer so I may have a hard time understand the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *regex* `/^[a-z]{3}([a-z]|\s)\d{3}$/gi`

Explanation

- ^ asserts start of string
- [a-z]{3} checks 3 consecutive letters
- `([a-z]|\s)` is either a letter or a space (based on 4th point)
- `\d{3}` checks 3 consecutive digits

**Demo**

```js
var isValid = (str) => !!str.match(/^[a-z]{3}([a-z]|\s)\d{3}$/g);

console.log( isValid( "asdf123" ) ); //valid

console.log( isValid( "asd 123" ) ); //valid

console.log( isValid( "asdf 123" ) ); //invalid
```

Comment: This `([a-z]|\s)` is equal to this `[a-z\s]` in matching.